# Facebook status post via app doesn't show in Newsfeed

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, restfb

I am using facebook graph api to post a status to Facebook via my app.

> The problem is I can't see the status post in NewsFeed, but in the
>   Wall of the user.

I just used `me/feed` accordingly to GraphAPI documentation.

When I searched this issue, I saw quite similar thing http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/302089206530370.

This one is quite similar one too .[Facebook graph post on feed is not visible in newsfeed](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8922085/facebook-graph-post-on-feed-is-not-visible-in-newsfeed), but that api is deprecated a long time ago and not the same API that I am using.

This one is exactly the same like my issue. http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/353691264693202 but sadly, facebook doesn't provide info in detail. can't find the duplicate issue.

I asked for `scope=user_photos,read_stream,publish_stream,offline_access,user_status,friends_status` grant access for my app.

Is there anything that I missing out?

Edited: I confirmed my setting of whether I have set to hide my app post in my newsfeed too. But I didn't set it.

Comment: Please post your code so we can take a look.

Comment: I think that is the facebook bug. already found the similar one reported bug.http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/372776119424090?browse=search_4fc3354fb769c0726100997 Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that is the facebook bug. already found the similar one reported http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/372776119424090?browse=search_4fc3354fb769c0726100997

For the time being, I can only wait for Facebook to fix that bug.

Thanks.